# Números aleatórios de 1 a 3 sem repetição

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto Web relacionado a um sistema de teste **A/B**, e necessito de um função que gere números aleatórios de **1** a **3** sem repetir os que já foram gerados.

```
function getRandom(max){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + 1); }
```

Comment: O que você já programou ? Tem algum código ?

Comment: function getRandom(max){  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + 1);  }

Answer (score 3):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
```

Para não repetir basta você armazenar os que já foram gerados num array e inserir uma condicional. Algo como:

```
 var numSorteados = [];
var numSorteios = 10;
var numAtual = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= numSorteios; i++){
  numAtual = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  if(numAtual != 0){
    if(numSorteados.indexOf(numAtual) ==-1){
     numSorteados.push(numAtual);
     window.alert("O número sorteado foi "+numAtual);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Como ficaria ele com o array , não saquei ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c586veqo/

Comment: Parece funcionar +1. dica pode postar sua resposta da duplicada...